# Как сделать запрос в базу данных 1С-битрикс правильно

Tags: битрикс

Есть сайт на 1С-битрикс.. Нужно сделать запрос в базу данных на все товары .. Чтобы запрос выдал: наименование товара, количество по складам для определенного клиента , цену для определенной группы клиентов..

Запрос должен делаться по айди клиента.. Как это сделать я просто не представляю.. 
Есть класс https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_help/catalog/classes/ccatalogstoreproduct/index.php но как им пользоваться я чет до конца не пойму..

Comment: я чет не пойму как вы пытаетесь им воспользоваться и в чем у вас проблема. в теме вопроса вы указываете запрос к 1С а в содержании ссылка на метод битрикса. определитесь к чему обращаться будете.

Comment: Я же говорю что не в курсе как делать... Написал сюда чтоб хоть чутка направили на правильеый путь

Comment: Так куда вы запрос собираетесь отправить? К базе данных сайта или базе 1С? 1С-Битрикс и 1С это совершенно разные вещи.

Comment: Ну и так же вопрос зачем. то что вы хотите делать отдельным запросом к базе, если компоненты и так это умеют выводить пользователю. Не совсем понятна цель ваших действий и какой результат вы хотите получить.

Comment: поясните, что дальше хотите делать с результатом выборки. и кто такой "клиент"? как он связан с товарами? показалось, что вы говорите про поставщика?

Comment: Простите за не ясность.. Мне надо сделать такой запрос . Чтоб потом формировать файл для клиента..Клиент-Покупатель .. Нужно сделать запрос в 1С-битрикс.. Я понял что это разные вещи.. Еще раз извеняюсь за не ясность

Comment: А что означает количество товара для определенного клиента? Есть ограничение на то с каких складов клиент может покупать?

Answer (score 0):

```
//Формируем массив данных
$products = array();
$StoreArray = array();

$arGroups = CUser::GetUserGroup($USER->GetID());//Группа покупателя
$userID = $USER->GetID();//Айди клиента
$rsUser = CUser::GetByID($userID);//Массив с данными клиента
$arUser = $rsUser->Fetch(); // Выборка данных с массива о клиенте
$arrayStoreUser = $arUser["UF_STORE"]; // Массив доп поля



//Выобрка товаров

$arSelect = Array("ID", "NAME", "DATE_ACTIVE_FROM", "SECTION_ID", 'IBLOCK_ID');
$arFilter = Array(
    "IBLOCK_ID"=>10,
    "SECTION_ID"=>array(305,329,350,351,363,378,410,417,437), /// Это массив для разделов
    "INCLUDE_SUBSECTIONS"=>"Y" // тут указали выбор подразделов
);

$res = CIBlockElement::GetList(Array(), $arFilter, false, Array(), $arSelect);
$var = 0;
while($ob = $res->GetNextElement())
{
    $arFields = $ob->GetFields();


    $rsStore = CCatalogStoreProduct::GetList(array(), array('PRODUCT_ID' => $arFields['ID'], 'STORE_ID' => $arrayStoreUser), false, false, array('AMOUNT'));

    //Количество товара по складу
    $rsStoreProduct = \Bitrix\Catalog\StoreProductTable::getList(array(

        'filter' => array('=PRODUCT_ID'=>$arFields['ID'],'STORE_ID'=>$arrayStoreUser),
        'select' => array('AMOUNT','STORE_TITLE' => 'STORE.TITLE','STORE_ID','PRODUCT_NAME' => 'PRODUCT.IBLOCK_ELEMENT.NAME')

    ));
    //Группа товара
    $groupProduct = CIBlockElement::GetByID($arFields['ID']);

    //Выборка цен для группы
    $db_res = CPrice::GetList(
        array(),
        array(
            "PRODUCT_ID" => $arFields['ID'],
            "CATALOG_GROUP_ID" => max($arGroups)
        )
    );

    if ($arStore = $rsStore->Fetch()) {
        $products[$arFields['ID']]["product_title"] =  $arFields['NAME'];
        if ($ar_res = $db_res->Fetch())
        {
            $products[$arFields['ID']]["PRICE"] = $ar_res['PRICE'];
        }
        else
        {
            $products[$arFields['ID']]["PRICE"] =  "Цена не найдена!";
        }
        //Выборка группы товара
        if($obRes = $groupProduct->GetNextElement())
        {
            $array_Group = $obRes->GetGroups();
            $nameGroup = $array_Group->Fetch();
            $products[$arFields['ID']]['Group'] = $nameGroup['NAME'];

        }
    }



    while($arStoreProduct = $rsStoreProduct->fetch())
    {
//        $products[$arFields['NAME']]['STORE_TITLE'. $var++] = $arStoreProduct['STORE_TITLE'];
        $products[$arFields['ID']]['AMOUNT' . $var++] = $arStoreProduct['AMOUNT'];

        $StoreArray[]= $arStoreProduct['STORE_TITLE'];

    }


    $resultArray = array_unique($StoreArray);
};
```

Comment: Кому интересно решил эту проблему так